# How to upload list of images to firebase storage then store the url inside firestore with flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

in my flutter app i used multi image picker inside of a form. and i want to upload those images to firebase storage as `images/posts/${auth.currentUser!.email!}/images[index]` path. then after upload is complete i want to store the download url inside firestore. how can i do that?

```
 onPressed: () async {
                              // Get.to(ImagePost());
                              var storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
                              final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
                              widget.images.map((e) async {
                                TaskSnapshot snapshot = await storage
                                    .ref()
                                    .child(
                                        "posts/${auth.currentUser!.email!}/$e")
                                    .putFile(e!);
                              });
                            }
```

Comment: Have you checked with this [Documentation](https://sanjeepan23.medium.com/adding-images-to-firebase-storage-and-cloud-firestore-in-flutter-6f0a09de4a5e#:~:text=you%20can%20add%20images%20by,simply%20copy%2Dpaste%20the%20images.&text=For%20the%20above%20changes%20to,yaml%20file).

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni it sends the images to storage, but it also writes firestore documents to the length of the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming widget.images is an array of files. If that is the case then the following onPressed function will work for you:

```
onPressed: () async {
  var storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  List<String> urls = [];

  for(int i = 0; i < widget.images.length; i++) {
    String imagePath = "posts/${auth.currentUser!.email!}/images$i";
    TaskSnapshot snapshot = await storage.ref().child(imagePath).putFile(widget.images[i]);
    String downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    urls.add(downloadUrl);
  }

  await firestore.collection('imageUrls').doc(auth.currentUser!.uid).set({
    'urls': urls
  });
}
```

Here I have implemented `for loop` which uploads the files inside `widget.images` and gets the download URL for the same and saves it in a list of strings called urls.
Then I am setting this list to a urls field in the specified document using the '.set()` method.

References: 1. [For setting Document](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#adding-documents),
2. [For file upload](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/upload-files/#upload-from-a-file)